# How to watch High quality youtube videos in movie player (totem)?

Tags: youtube, totem

I can watch you-tube videos in movie player by using you-tube plug-in for movie player but I need to watch videos in high quality . 
Thanks

Comment: Might not be possible, see [this OMGUbuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/totems-youtube-playback-to-enter-dark-ages/) from back in January 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try minitube. For some reason I dont know, it can play streams in high quality and has the opportunity to save those streams